# javascript not working properly in button hover effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make buttons hover effect on multiple buttons.
And for hovering effect I used java script. This javascript is working properly only in one button.
Hover effect is that when I hover mouse from any part of button, hovering I start from their and also end from their only, and it covers all part of body of button.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.onmousemove = function(e) {
  const x = e.pageX - btn.offsetLeft;
  const y = e.pageY - btn.offsetTop;

  btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
  btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
}
```

```css
.button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.button .btn {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 19px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #42CDE7;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button .btn span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.button .btn::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--y);
  left: var(--x);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #42CDE7;
  transition: width 0.7s, height 0.7s;
}

.button .btn:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="" class="btn"><span>BUTTON 1</span></a>
  <a href="" class="btn"><span>BUTTON 2</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: `querySelector` only selects one element, where `querySelectorAll` gives you an array of elements (a nodelist, more specifically), that you then need to loop through to add the eventlistener.

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: @lucumt I want to see in all buttons as seen in the first button

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
for(i=0;i<btns.length;i++){
let btn = btns[i];
btn.onmousemove = function(e) {
  const x = e.pageX - btn.offsetLeft;
  const y = e.pageY - btn.offsetTop;

  btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
  btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
}
}
```

```css
.button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.button .btn {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 19px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #42CDE7;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button .btn span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.button .btn::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--y);
  left: var(--x);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #42CDE7;
  transition: width 0.7s, height 0.7s;
}

.button .btn:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="" class="btn"><span>BUTTON 1</span></a>
  <a href="" class="btn"><span>BUTTON 2</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank U so much. your js runs well

Answer (score 0):

To select all of the buttons use `querySelectorAll`. Then use `forEach` to add event listeners to each button.

Identify which button is being hovered over by using `e.currentTarget`. `e.currentTarget` will be the button to which the event listener was attached.

And finally, use `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY` as the new `x` and `y` coordinates.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

btns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('mousemove', onmousemove));

function onmousemove(e) {
  const btn = e.currentTarget;
  const x = e.offsetX;
  const y = e.offsetY;

  btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
  btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
}
```

```css
.button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.button .btn {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 19px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #42CDE7;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button .btn span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.button .btn::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--y);
  left: var(--x);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #42CDE7;
  transition: width 0.7s, height 0.7s;
}

.button .btn:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="" class="btn"><span>BUTTON 1</span></a>
  <a href="" class="btn"><span>BUTTON 2</span></a>
</div>
```